# Delphi Insert data from StringGrid to a Database Table

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Iam trying to insert data from a StringGrid to the Oracle DB table for that i tried like below.

```
function TfrmMapping.LoadtoTable: Boolean;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  lQuery, s: string;
  lData: TArray<string>;
begin

  for I := 0 to vTableColumns.count - 1 do
  begin
    if I <> vTableColumns.count - 1 then
    begin
      s := s + vTableColumns[I] + ',';
    end
    else
    begin
      s := s + vTableColumns[I];
    end;
  end;

  for I := 1 to StrGrdLoadCSVData.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    vSortedGrid.Add(StrGrdLoadCSVData.Rows[I].CommaText);
  end;

  for I := 0 to vSortedGrid.count - 1 do
  begin
    lQuery := 'Insert into ' + cmbBXDBTables.Text + '(' + s + ') values(' +
      vSortedGrid[I] + ')';
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.SQL.Add(lQuery);
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

In the code , Iam adding all the data of StringGrid(StrGrdLoadCSVData) to a StringList(vSortedGrid), and now iam trying to loop through the StringList to add each row to the DB, But Iam not able to insert because my is taking the values like this

```
Insert into abc(sno,Name)values(1,welcome);
```

It is because there are no quotes to `welcome` it is giving an error.

it is error like this : `[FireDAC][Phys][Ora]ORA-00984:column not allowed here`

How i can modify my code to insert the data successfully to Db.

**EDIT**

My table Structure is :

```
Name            Type
 ---------  ------------
 SNO          NUMBER(38)
 NAME         VARCHAR2(15)
```

my desired result in the table should be like this :

```
       SNO NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Hello
         2 Welcome
```

The values in the table comming from the string List

Comment: Use `QuotedStr()`

Comment: `'Insert into abc(SNO,NAME) values(''1,welcome'')'`  if i use Quotedstr, it is getting values like this and giving an error like

`[FireDAC][Phys][Ora]ORA-00947:not enough values` 

if there is no Quotedstring it is error like this : 

`[FireDAC][Phys][Ora]ORA-00984:column not allowed here`

Comment: You can try my answer.

Comment: What you mean by `Null?` ? Is that a `column` ?

Comment: It is not Column, The table has only two columns. `SNO` and `NAME` where `SNO` is of `number / integer type` and `NAME` is of `VARCHAR`

Comment: When inserting to a StringList, if the value is a string type, then insert it to a StringList with quotes associated with the value.

Comment: @Fero68, Is there any possibility to avoid the StringList , and insert from the StringGrid to DB Table.

Comment: Yes you can, by getting the value straight from the StringGrid then you would have to use TStringGrid.Row and applying your cell properties, then using that value and inserting straight to the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Modified the Code like below

```
function TfrmMapping.LoadtoTable: Boolean;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  lQuery, s, lcolvalues: string;
begin

  for I := 0 to vTableColumns.count - 1 do
  begin
    if I <> vTableColumns.count - 1 then
    begin
      s := s + vTableColumns[I] + ',';
    end
    else
    begin
      s := s + vTableColumns[I];
    end;
  end;

  for I := 1 to StrGrdLoadCSVData.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to vTableColumns.count - 1 do
    begin
      if J <> vTableColumns.count - 1 then
      begin
        lcolvalues := lcolvalues +
          QuotedStr(StrGrdLoadCSVData.Cells[J, I]) + ',';
      end
      else
      begin
        lcolvalues := lcolvalues + QuotedStr(StrGrdLoadCSVData.Cells[J, I]);
      end;
    end;
    lQuery := 'Insert into ' + cmbBXDBTables.Text + '(' + s + ') values (' +
      lcolvalues + ')';
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.SQL.Add(lQuery);
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

    lcolvalues := '';
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

This is inserting values to Table from the string grid, I didn't use Parameter passing as of now. I have to try that also for ensuring more security.

Thank You @Sami , Buy using your concept of FDQuery I have got this idea...

Comment: Good luck man , all what I can say is , I come to SO for help other as I can  and learn from them , that's the life .Together Everyone Achieves more **(TEAM)**.

Answer (score 2):

> It is because there are no quotes to welcome it is giving an error.

So from what you say :

```
  for I := 0 to vSortedGrid.count - 1 do
  begin
    lQuery := 'Insert into ' + cmbBXDBTables.Text + '(' + s + ') values('+IntToStr(i+1)+',' +
      QuotedStr(vSortedGrid[I]) + ')';
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.SQL.Add(lQuery);
    DataModSample.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

**Note:** Better to use `parameters`.

**Update:**

Another option to insert from `TStringGrid` using `TFDTable`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var I : Integer;
begin

for i := 1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do

    begin
     try
      FDTable1.Append;
      FDTable1SNO.Value := StrToInt( StringGrid1.Cells[0,i] );
      FDTable1SName.Value := StringGrid1.Cells[1,i];
      FDTable1.Post;
      except on E: Exception do
        begin
         MessageDlg(E.Message,mtError,[mbOK],0);
         MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
       end;
    end;
end;
```

Another option to insert from the `TStringGrid` using `TFDQuery` (avoid SQL Injection):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var I : Integer;   TableName : String;
begin

TableName := 'Table1';

for i := 1 to StringGrid1.RowCount-1 do

    begin
     try
      FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Insert Into '+TableName+' Values(:Val1 , :Val2)' ;
      FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('Val1').Value := StrToInt( StringGrid1.Cells[0,i] );
      FDQuery1.Params.ParamByName('Val2').Value := StringGrid1.Cells[1,i];
      FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
     except on E: Exception do
      begin
       MessageDlg(E.Message,mtError,[mbOK],0);
       MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
      end;
    end;
```

You can also `Create parameters` as you need at `Runtime` for exemple:

```
FDQuery1.Params.CreateParam(ftString,'ParamName',ptInput) ;
```

Also you can use `GetTableNames()` to get all tables in the `Database`.

Comment: `'Insert into abc(SNO,NAME) values(1,''1,welcome'')'`

`  SNO NAME
---------- -----------
         1 1,Welcome `  

It is inserting like above, but i want like this 

  SNO NAME
---------- -----------
        1 welcome

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this , So Please edit your question and add your table structure and the resault expected.

Comment: `Note: Better to use parameters.`  How can  i use parameters , here The Table which I am inserting is not same all time , the table will change depending on user selection and the no of columns also will change.

Comment: @userhi if there are many tables, use one statement and one parameter set per table, it is more robust, supports more field types, and removes SQL injection risks

Comment: @mjn42 , How it can be done, Can you guide me in achieveing this?